# Reading from a stream with mixed XML and plain text

Tags: c#, .net, xml, stream

I have a text stream that contains segments of both arbitrary plain text and well-formed xml elements. How can I read it and extract the xml elements only? XmlReader with ConformanceLevel set to Fragment still throws an exception when it encounters plain text, which to it is malformed xml.

Any ideas? Thanks

Here's my code so far:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings))
    while (!reader.EOF)
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(reader.ReadSubtree());
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }
```

Here's a sample stream content and I have no control over it by the way:

```html
Found two objects:
Object a
<object>
    <name>a</name>
    <description></description>
</object>
Object b
<object>
    <name>b</name>
    <description></description>
</object>
```

Comment: This is not XML, if you have plain text. Don't try to parse it as Xml. Can you describe more precisely what is the format of the source? And maybe HtmlAgilityPack can help you, it can parse Html, which is a mix of nodes and plain text.

Comment: I know it isn't, otherwise this would've been much easier! I've added a sample stream content (don't know how to turn off color-highlighting here .. sorry)

Comment: For the syntax highlighting, you can force the language using `<!-- language: lang-html -->` (see the help more info). You should give a try to HtmlAgility pack, regarding your source stream. Or do you have a reliable way to know what's plain text and what's xml (something like a know pattern : 1 text, 1 xml node, 1 text, 1 xml node, etC.)

Comment: just contain the whole thing in a tag and it's xml. 
quoting W3C XML 1.0 "An element type has mixed content when elements of that type may contain character data, optionally interspersed with child elements."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that this is a hack, if you wrap your mixed document with a "fake" xml root node, you should be able to do what you need getting only the nodes of type element (i.e. skipping the text nodes) among the children of the root element:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;

static class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        string mixed = @"
Found two objects:
Object a
<object>
    <name>a</name>
    <description></description>
</object>
Object b
<object>
    <name>b</name>
    <description></description>
</object>
";
        string xml = "<FOO>" + mixed + "</FOO>";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        var xmlFragments = from XmlNode node in doc.FirstChild.ChildNodes 
                           where node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element 
                           select node;
        foreach (var fragment in xmlFragments) {
            Console.WriteLine(fragment.OuterXml);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Glad it helped, even if I cannot grant that it won't explode for slightly different inputs :)