# XmlReader is too greedy

Tags: c#, xml, stream

I am trying to consume content off a tcp stream that looks like:

```
1
2
<Xml att='value'>
    <Child> ... </Child>
</Xml>
3
4
```

using code such as:

```
var one = Convert.ToInt32(_tcpReader.ReadLine());  // ok
var two = Convert.ToInt32(_tcpReader.ReadLine());  // ok

using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(_tcpReader))
{
    xmlReader.MoveToContent();
    var xmlElement = XElement.Load(xmlReader);  // dies
    //(XElement) XNode.ReadFrom(xmlReader);  // also dies
}

var three = Convert.ToInt32(_tcpReader.ReadLine());
var four = Convert.ToInt32(_tcpReader.ReadLine());
```

The problem is that both `XElement.Load` and `XNode.ReadFrom` complain about invalid content at the root level; presumably the 3.  In both cases, the XmlReader is observed to be currently on the "Xml" EndElement.  I want the XmlReader to stop trying to consume content from the underlying stream after it has found the end element, so that subsequent reads from the stream (i.e. three, four) will succeed.

Also, of course, I don't want the XmlReader to close the underlying stream after it has finished reading.

Comment: You may have to read the XML part yourself and store it in a string. XmlReader isn't being greedy; if you open an XML file and just read it until the first element is closed, you may miss out that there is, indeed, more than one root element and the file is invalid.

Comment: But that's just it: I don't want the XmlReader to read a _file_ from the underlying stream, I want it to read a single _element_ (and all its complex content).  Later on I will be reading more lines and elements from the same stream.

Comment: What I meant is that XmlReader is not made to read individual elements, and has to do this forward reading to be compliant. If you need it to read a subset of your stream, you'll have to isolate said subset yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555534/reading-from-a-stream-with-mixed-xml-and-plain-text?rq=1).  The XmlReader has to be set to read a fragment only, not a document.

```
using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(_tcpReader, 
    new XmlReaderSettings {ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment}))
{
    xmlReader.MoveToContent();
    var xmlElement = (XElement) XNode.ReadFrom(xmlReader);  // works!
}
```

Note that `XElement.Load` dies: reader is expected to be EOF after this operation.